# C++ Pointer Syntax ->

Tags: c++, pointers

I was trying to understand what a->b referred to and I was able to understand it refers to

```
(*a).b
```

where a is a pointer. What does a->b->c mean in those terms - i.e. is it (*((*a).b)).c?

Comment: thanks! so I could re-write it as i did

Comment: If you check an [operator precedence chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), you'll notice the associativity (which isn't precedence, but is often on the same chart) of `->` is left-to-right. This is enough to arrive at Matt's comment of `a->b->c` being parsed as `(a->b)->c`.

Comment: And it can't be `a->(b->c)` as `(b->c)` is not a member of `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `a->b->c` is equivalent to `(*(*a).b).c` which is equivalent to `(*((*a).b)).c`.